# Openpyxl failed to load a workbook

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to parse a workbook, but when I load it I am getting this error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'style'`

My code:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wb = load_workbook("./temp.xlsx")
    ws = wb.active
    result = {}
    countdown = 0
    for idx, row in enumerate(ws.iter_cols(min_row=9, min_col=9, max_col=213)):
        if countdown != 0:
            countdown -= 1
            pass
        if idx == 0:
            for i in range(1, len(row)):
                result[row[i]] = {}
        else:
            for i in range(1, len(row)):
                result[f"Sample {i}"][row[0]] = row[i]
            countdown = 3
    print(result)
```

The only problem I can think of is that I downloaded this xlsx from google sheets, so maybe there is something wrong with it, but I can't understand what exactly. Unfortunately, I cannot attach this document because it's confidential.

Comment: This is probably #1589